# MVC and areas of razor pages in same project .net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have an area in MVC project. In the area section I have razor pages project in .NET Core. How can I map both routes? When I visit `https://localhost:44361/` then main project should be run and if I visit `https://localhost:44361/backend` then the area of razor pages should be run.

Comment: What do you mean `if I visit https://localhost:44361/backend then the area of razor pages should be run.`When you use `endpoints.MapRazorPages();`,it means you configures razor page routing.When you add Area name to the routing,it will go to the area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Razor pages is using folder-based routing as default, you may create folder **Pages/Backend**, and use a standard setup as shown below.

The same solution using areas: Create folder **Areas/Backend/Pages** and use the setup shown below.

In Startup#ConfigureServices

```
services.AddControllers();
services.AddRazorPages();
```

In Startup#Configure

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
   endpoints.MapRazorPages();
   endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

Both approaches above are verified by creating a MVC-app and added support for Razor pages by adding `services.AddRazorPages();` and `endpoints.MapRazorPages();`.

More information about areas:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-5.0#areas-with-razor-pages

Comment: its not working in Areas. all of this configuration has defined in startup.cs but still not working 
 > Areas
     > backend
           > pages
                edit.razor
http://localhost:59722/backend/edit   still not working

Comment: @SameerUllah: I've just verified my answer by creating a new MVC app, then added services.AddRazorPages(); and endpoints.MapRazorPages();, added directory Pages/Backend, and finally added a page to Pages/Backend, and it is working.

I also tested to use Areas by adding directory Areas/Backend/Pages and added a page to that directory. It works too without any changes in Startup. BR